# How to indefinitely wait for named pipe creation?

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

I've got a client which connects to named pipe. Very often this named pipe doesn't not exist so client connection fails. Client should connect to a pipe as a soon as possible because sometimes server sends commands to a connected client and sometimes client notifies server about it's state.

Is there a way to wait for named pipe creation indefinitely?
Basically I want to avoid endless calls to connect/sleep which takes CPU time. Ideal solution would be to avoid even thread creation.

There's a function `WaitNamedPipe` but it actually waits for pipe to be available and if it doesn't exist it returns immediately. I believe that's why `NamedPipeClientStream.Connect` returns immediately when timeout is not specified.

Are there any other IPC that suits this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Have the client create a named event and wait on that. When the server starts, it should create the pipe and then open the named event. If the event does not exist, no client is waiting. If the event does exist, the server signals it and the client's wait ends, and the client knows that the pipe is ready.

To avoid potential for races, use a common named mutex to serialize these steps.

Comment: And if the client and server are on different machines?  Named pipes can be used across a network.  Named kernel objects, like events, cannot.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The reference to IPC led me to assume that the pipe is on the same machine

Comment: Not all IPCs are limited to the local machine.  Most notably, pipes, mailslots, sockets, etc.